# Change pattern just in next column matching another pattern

Tags: awk

This is the header of my file:

```
1 HAVANA gene 11869 14409 . + . gene_name "DDX11L1" remap_original_location "chr1:+:11869-14409"
1 HAVANA gene 118569 148409 . + . gene_name "ORF21" remap_original_location "chr1:+:118569-148409" clinSig 0.59
1 HAVANA transcript 118568 148419 . + . remap_original_location "chr1:+:118568-148419" clinSig 0.02 M .
MT HAVANA gene 226 399 . + . remap_original_location "chrM:+:226-399" * + 3
MT HAVANA * 27 . -
```

I would like to save to another file exactly the same content than this, but just removing the `chr` pattern and transforming `M` to `MT` pattern in the column next to the column matching `remap_original_location`.

So, my desired output is:

```
1 HAVANA gene 11869 14409 . + . gene_name "DDX11L1" remap_original_location "1:+:11869-14409"
1 HAVANA gene 118569 148409 . + . gene_name "ORF21" remap_original_location "1:+:118569-148409" clinSig 0.59
1 HAVANA transcript 118568 148419 . + . remap_original_location "1:+:118568-148419" clinSig 0.02 M .
MT HAVANA gene 226 399 . + . remap_original_location "MT:+:226-399" * + 3
MT HAVANA * 27 . -
```

Do you know how can I achieve this?

I am trying some code like this:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i=="remap_original_location"){print ??? }}}'
```

But I am not sure how to specify the print part. In addition, as you can see, not all rows present the pattern `remap_original_location` and yet I still want to prin them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk '{gsub(/chr/, ""); for (i=1; i<NF; ++i) if ($i == "remap_original_location") {gsub(/M/, "MT", $(i+1)); break}} 1' file

1 HAVANA gene 11869 14409 . + . gene_name "DDX11L1" remap_original_location "1:+:11869-14409"
1 HAVANA gene 118569 148409 . + . gene_name "ORF21" remap_original_location "1:+:118569-148409" clinSig 0.59
1 HAVANA transcript 118568 148419 . + . remap_original_location "1:+:118568-148419" clinSig 0.02 M .
MT HAVANA gene 226 399 . + . remap_original_location "MT:+:226-399" * + 3
MT HAVANA * 27 . -
```

A more readable form:

```sh
awk '{
   gsub(/chr/, "")
   for (i=1; i<NF; ++i)
      if ($i == "remap_original_location") {
         gsub(/M/, "MT", $(i+1))
         break
      }
} 1' file
```

Answer (score 3):

With `perl`:

```sh
perl -pe 's/remap_original_location "\Kchr(M)?/$1 ? "MT" : ""/e' ip.txt
```

- `remap_original_location "` I'm assuming single space to be consistent between fields here and that the next field will always start with `"` character. You can adjust the regex for other variations if needed
- `\K` preceding portion won't be part of the matched text to be replaced
- `(M)?` optionally match `M` character
- `$1 ? "MT" : ""` if first capture group isn't empty, use `MT` as replacement string, else use empty string

  - empty string is *Falsy* in Perl
  - you can also use `$1 && "MT"` instead of ternary expression in this case, since the *Falsy* value is same as the alternate value needed
- `e` flag helps to use Perl code in replacement section

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
awk '
{
  gsub(/chr/,"")
}
match($0,/remap_original_location "M:/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/"M:/,"\"MT:",val)
  $0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1) val substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
1'  Input_file
```

OR as per Sundeep's comment one could try following too:

```
awk '{gsub(/chr/,""); sub(/remap_original_location "M/, "&T")} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: Good idea, but you can simplify it to `awk '{gsub(/chr/,""); sub(/remap_original_location "M/, "&T")} 1'`

Comment: @Sundeep, Thanks, added this solution as a alternative with credits, thank you.